# Clear method Glide Android

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a question about Glide's clear method. Docs says:

**Cancel any pending loads Glide may have for the view and free any resources that may have been loaded for the view.**

Which resources it is referring to? Deletes image from disk and cache? or clear the reference to imageView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource here is referring to any loaded bitmap data or drawables which was supposed to be loaded inside the view.

Comment: So it returns ImageView to its default state?

Comment: Presumably, yes.